# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::count()

Tags: php, fatal-error

I got this error in products.php page

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   stdClass::count() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopCart\navigation.php:29 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopCart\layout_head.php(27): include() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\shopCart\products.php(15):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\shopCart\navigation.php on line 29

This is the error part of navigation.php page. Last line is 29

```
// count products in cart
$cart_item = new \stdClass();
$cart_item->user_id=1; // default to user with ID "1" for now
$cart_count=$cart_item->count();
```

This is count function in cartItem class

```
class CartItem{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "cart_items";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $product_id;
    public $quantity;
    public $user_id;
    public $created;
    public $modified;

    // constructor
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
    // count user's items in the cart
    public function count() {

            // query to count existing cart item
            $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE user_id=:user_id";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

            // sanitize
            $this->user_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->user_id));

            // bind category id variable
            $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $this->user_id);

            // execute query
            $stmt->execute();

            // get row value
            $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            // return
            return $rows[0];
        }
}
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: How can you run a function which doesn't exist? You created a object and immediately tried to access a function within it which you never defined? What you are trying to do is `$cart_item = new CartItem($db)`.

Comment: Your `$cart_item` variable is not an object of class `CartItem`. It is a `stdClass`. The `stdClass` class doesn't have any properties or methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating `$cart_item` as a `stdClass` object. I am assuming from your code example and class it should be instantiated as a `CartItem` object, like so:

```
$cart_item = new CartItem($db);
```

You were getting the error because `stdClass` doesn't have a `count()` method.